# Goldbach Conjecture predicate form?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, goldbachs-conjecture

I am learning logic, and when I was taking a quiz one of the multiple choice questions was "Which of the following is an unsolved conjecture?" I picked the following answer because I thought it was the Goldbach Conjecture. However, this is not the right answer. What am i missing?

$\forall m \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n \geqslant m, \text{ $n$ even},\exists p,q \in P, n=p+q$

The correct answer was:
$\forall m \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n \geqslant m, n\in P \text{ and } n+2 \in P$

However, why Is the first one not also correct?

Comment: Really? In a logic course they write $\exists n\ge m$ and ask stuff like this?

Comment: The Goldbach Conjecture speaks about "*every* even integer $n$". Your claim only concerns an infinite number of such $n$'s. I don't know an argument right of my head of why that's true, though.

Comment: @NikolajK lol i'm an idiot, but thank you

Answer (score 2):

The statement
$$
\forall m \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n \geqslant m, \text{ $n$ even},\exists p,q \in P, n=p+q
$$
means that for any $m$, THERE EXISTS a larger-than-$m$, even integer that is the sum of two primes. This is obvious--just take two larger-than-$m$ primes and add them together.

The Goldbach conjecture instead says that ALL even integers ($\ge 4$) are the sum of two primes, not just that THERE EXISTS sufficiently large such even integers. It's a much stronger statement.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "correct answer" is a statement of the [Twin primes conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime).

Comment: The question is why the first is not correct.